# Scrapy: How to extract all words that are inside HTML-tags?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Python's Scrapy and want to get all words that are inside html-tags  using selectors.
For example, I have this page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<div>Hello 
    <span>World!<b>Yes it is</b></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I need to get from this either string or list with all words:

```py
"My Page My First Heading My First paragraph. Hello World! Yes it is"
```

or

```py
["My", "Page", "My", "First", "Heading", "My", "First", "paragraph.", "Hello", "World!", "Yes", "it", "is"]
```

or even words without punctuation marks.
How to do this? I tried using `response.selector.xpath('//text()').extract()` but got many unwanted results like empty strings, symbols of new line (`\n`) and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.xpath('//text()').extract()` is a good way to approach the problem. You just need the power of [input and output processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors) to filter out empty items, stripping etc.

---

Alternatively, you may use [`re:test()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions) to require at least one *alphanumeric* to be present in a text:

```
response.xpath('//text()[re:test(., "\w+")]').extract()
```

Example:

```
In [1]: map(unicode.strip, response.xpath('//text()[re:test(., "\w+")]').extract())
Out[1]: 
[u'My Page',
 u'My First Heading',
 u'My first paragraph.',
 u'Hello',
 u'World!',
 u'Yes it is']
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I like the variant with `.re(r'\w+')`, why you deleted it?

Comment: @Kantrael I think `.re()` could be tweaked to be used here too (with positive lookarounds I suppose), just not the way I've proposed - it had left us with texts containing only alphanumerics which is not correct - we basically needed a regex test which is exactly what `re:test()` does. Plus, I like that it's inside the expression. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, edited answer looks very pretty, I'll try to use it, thanks again!